# Identifying duplicates in python hash and raising an exception and printing the duplicate value

Tags: python

I have a hash in my code, `hash1 = [val1, val2, val3]`--
and have multiple such hashes-- hash1....hashn.

I would like to do a comparison where in hash1...hashn, if they match all the values, it should print out the values and raise an exception, how can I do this?

i.e.,

```
hash1 = (1234, "this is me", 456, "hello")
hash2 = (2345, "hello from adele", 456, "hello again")
........
hashn = (1234, "this is me", 456, "hello")
```

hash1 = hashn-- raise an exception and print hashn values

How do I go about doing this check in python? I don't want to use collections and would prefer doing by list/map.

Comment: Let python check it. e.g. use a set

Comment: It's simple enough to do this, but be aware that duplicate hash values are not an error.

Comment: A set just removes the duplicates, I would like to know what those duplicate entries were and raise an exception if any duplicates were found @Pynchia

Comment: And yes, it's not the duplicate hash values that's a problem but any two hashes being duplicate.. Thanks for pointing that @user2357112

Comment: Why don’t you want to use collections? It seems like Counter would be an ideal solution here.

Answer (score 0):

In Python `tuple` equality works element-by-element, so you can simply do

```
if hash1 == hash2:
    ...
```

If all of them are in a list a `O(n^2)` solution would be

```
def check_dups(L):
    for i in range(len(L)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(L)):
            if L[i] == L[j]:
                ...
```

or using `any`:

```
def check_dups(L):
    for i in range(len(L)):
        if any(L[i] == L[j] for j in range(i+1, len(L))):
            ...
```

A more efficient way if there is a big number of elements would be to do a sort and then a linear scan (duplicates will end up adjacent in a a sorted list because for `tuple`s `a < b` works as lexicographic order on the elements).

Another even faster option would be to use a `dict` with the `tuple`s as keys and the index as value (or a `set` if you don't care about what is the conflicting index in the original list). This would work because `tuple`s are considered "values" and not "objects" and thus identity is not considered.

Comment: `This would work because tuples are considered "values" and not "objects"` - false. There's no "value"/"object" distinction; tuples are ordinary objects. They're just immutable, and hashable as long as their elements are hashable. Identity is considered for tuples exactly as much as it is for lists.